# Getting nginx 500 error on post request Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, ajax, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, nestjs

I created Elastic Beanstalk on Node.js platform and successfully deployed my app. I deployed manualy via clicking "Upload and Deploy" button and choosing zip file. This project is for education purposes. But this problem can be encountered in real life as well.
For some reason I receive 500 "Internal server error" when I try to sign up. Validation methods working fine and I can see validation messages. I didn't configure nginx at all.
I presume that problem connected with nginx and some port conflicts but I haven't enough experience in this area and I need someone's help.

Here is node.js server code https://github.com/andreyohiienko/nestjs-task-management

Here is sing up form http://nest-task-management-frontend.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/ there are no emails needed, you can use any valid data you want.

And last 100 logs https://elasticbeanstalk-eu-west-1-108292904570.s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/resources/environments/logs/tail/e-mr33wd92kp/i-00a73d864981d8b9b/TailLogs-1603988558758.txt?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20201029T162240Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIOTEDYBZFNPDBGEQ%2F20201029%2Feu-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=ed69d16da09bcf795924006039bd43278a8d8a27d3571343f5ed7ff31a984fca

My questions is:

1. what is the problem?
2. Why do validation messages work?
3. And how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Andrew, based on your logs, I would do a few things, does your action handler (or whatever handles your post) have an error callback? Looks like not from your logs (No callback function was given.) I would log the backtrace from the error so you get more than that in your logs. Second, you can ssh into your instance and view the application logs directly, this might help with debugging. You can also log the request with headers here so you can see if cloudfront or the loadbalancer are stripping things out of your request, or not allowing cookies etc.

Comment: What is the corresponding nginx error log entry?

Comment: @JP Silvashy, thanks for your answer. You were right the problem is in "No callback function was given" I googled this sentences and found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in "bcrypt-nodejs". I just replaced it to 'bcryptjs'.